# Why can't Alphonse repair Edward's automail using alchemy?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

Edward's automail breaks many times during animation, but every time even if Alphonse didn't take any damage they go after Winrey to fix Edward's automail. Now I'm wondering if Alphonse can easily repair a radio or any other mechanical device, why can't he fix Edward's automail? Also, why does neither Edward nor Alphonse try enhancing automail using alchemy?

Comment: Edward uses alchemy to enhance his automail, the spike or knife at the top of his automail came from himself. he modified his automail to get it.

Comment: @Tartori I was talking about the materials used in the automail, enhancing as in making his automail strong enough so it doesn't break.

Comment: Ok, then just read Madara Uchiha answer, it covers this one to.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The first step of alchemy is *understanding*. That means, understanding the raw materials you are going to use, and how to break them down. It also means to understand the resulting item. You can't make something you don't know anything about.

A radio is a very simple device. It contains little to none electronics, and is rather easy to *understand*.

An automail on the other hand, is a very complicated piece of engineering. It contains engines, circuit boards etc. Which make it hard for a "simple" alchemist to construct.

If Winry for example were to be an alchemist, she would probably be able to fix automail using alchemy, but even that would only be emergency fixes, and not a full repair.

Comment: Beat me to it. Hit every point I was working with. +1

Comment: But Alphonse also knows quite a lot of truth in the accident at the beginning of the story - which allows him to be able to use alchemy later in the story when his memory recovers. Shouldn't he be able to use that?

Comment: @nhahtdh: You must differentiate between Alchemy and Engineering. Just because you know how to manipulate matter, doesn't mean you know how to make a working automail.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: It is the truth of the world, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh the truth of the world refers to alchemy. It doesn't teach you everything, only alchemy.