# Are Elric brothers good at electronics?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

There is at least one situation per Elric brother, when they have fixed radio device - e.g. Edward fixed transmitter sg. Fuery was working on, and Alphonse fixed broken radio in Reole (Liore?).

One of the principles of the alchemy is that if you want to create some thing, you should know how it works. Which leads me to conclusion, that both Elric brothers should have some education in terms of electronic devices, and radio technology.

Is there any additional information on this in anime/manga etc?

Comment: There isn't any in the manga or Brotherhood adaptation (and _probably_ not in the 2003 series), but I don't know if there might be some in the light novels or guidebooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, in order to create something with alchemy, a general understanding of how the object to be created works is required. This was discussed in the answer for [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/why-cant-alphonse-repair-edwards-automail-using-alchemy). That means the Elric brothers must have some understanding of circuitry to fix a radio. They most likely came across it somewhere in their studies.